# export .csv file in flask using ajax

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am trying to upload a csv file from the page and send it to the backend made of python and flask, all the gets working fine, knowing that because backend returns:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2018 15:37:07] "GET /medal HTTP/1.1" 200

but nothing on the POST. Tried almost everything but no connections or messages.

**BACKEND POST:**

```
import pandas
  from calest import calest_app, client
from flask import request, jsonify
from..models.Medals import Medal

db = client.estadisticas
collection = db.medallas


@calest_app.route('/result', methods = ["POST"])
def post_discipline():
csv_received = request.files['file']
csv_file = pandas.read_csv(csv_received)
discipline_result = Medal(csv_file).get_medals_discipline()
gender_result = Medal(csv_file).get_medals_gender()
city_result = Medal(csv_file).get_medals_city()
country_result = Medal(csv_file).get_medals_country()
medals_result = Medal(csv_file).get_medals_by_medals()
sport_result = Medal(csv_file).get_medals_by_sport()
cursor = collection.insert({
  "discipline": discipline_result,
  "gender": gender_result,
  "city": city_result,
  "country": country_result,
  "medal": medals_result,
  "sport": sport_result
})
return jsonify("Added"), 201
```

**FRONTEND AJAX:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>

  < script >
  $("#form").on("submit", function (e) {

    var fileSelect = $("#csvFile");
    var files = fileSelect[0].files;
    // Create a new FormData object.
    var formData = new FormData();

    debugger;
    formData.append("#csvFile", files[0].name, files[0], files[0].name);
    <!--csv_received = request.-- >

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/result",
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,          // The content type used when sending data to the server.  
        cache: false,                // To unable request pages to be cached  
        processData: false,          // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false  
        success: function (data) {
          debugger;
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          debugger;
        }
      })
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Does the browser console give you any hints or errors? I'm fairly certain the problem is in the js because you're not receiving anything at all on the server side.

Comment: No I am not received anything in the backend console like it does with all the GET's, it just does not want to work with the POST,

Comment: I was referring to the browser console. You can enter it on any webpage by right clicking pretty much anywhere and clicking Inspect (element), and then head to the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

`formData.append` takes at most 3 parameters, you're passing 4.
The first parameter is the field name(not the id selector as you have it).
Second is the File/Blob/string data(where you put the file name).
Third field is the file name, which is really only necessary when you pass a Blob.
Since you use `file` as the field name in your server code use that as the first parameter

```
formData.append("file", files[0]);
```

Comment: Another thing to mention would be that you need to prevent the default action of the form if you're doing Ajax. So you'll need to put an `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of your submit handler function